# UIPickerView With Custom Dates

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdate, uipickerview

I cannot use a UIDatePicker.  I just want to throw that out at the very beginning before all the commenters tell me to just use a UIDatePicker.  I want to have a Picker Wheel that shows all the day of the year, leading up to today, and display it as Day: 1/Jan 1, Day: 2/Jan 2 and so on.  Here is what I have so far, which detects what day 'number' of the year it is, and populates the PickerWheel with all the dates leading up to today:

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSInteger dc = [currentCalendar  ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                              forDate:today];
    options = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int index = 1; index <= dc; index++)
    {
        NSString *pickerItemTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Day: %d", index];
        [options addObject: pickerItemTitle];
    }
```

What can I do to make it also match up the NSInteger with the date, and have that be part of the pickerItemTitle as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.  Added some code to form a date based off integer of day into the loop.  Now, the viewWillAppear method that sets the array for the uipickerview looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSInteger dc = [currentCalendar  ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                              forDate:today];
    options = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int index = 1; index <= dc; index++)
    {
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setDay:index];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];
        NSString *articleDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSString *pickerItemTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Day: %d/%@", index, articleDateString];
        [options addObject: pickerItemTitle];
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];  
}
```